# Single word for "mental endurance"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Could anyone tell me what a single word for **mental endurance** could be... I'm thinking something along the lines of willpower, but less ambiguous, it should fit in the following sentence:

"...has a great desire for improvement and puts a lot of effort in it, but has issues in terms of confidence and (?)"

Thanks!

Comment: That fits well, but I'm thinking something between stability and endurance, like a "resistance to mental burnout" type of thing...

Comment: It's not one word, but what about "mental fortitude"?

Comment: As Matt's example, not one word - but "mental stamina"?

Comment: @mplungjan I think the word is 'perseverance'.

Comment: Really grateful for mental fortitude, but as you yourself have pointed out it's not one word. Will consider it for future use, but I think "tenacity" pretty much hit the nail on the head in this case. It's not a perfect fit, but it's really close while being a single word, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: There has been some discussion about 'stoicism' on another post this morning. That must also be a close match.

Comment: "Stoicism" sounds a bit too... philosophical to me. But a good suggestion nonetheless. By the way, in the end I decided to go with both tenacity and mental fortitude. "...has a great desire for improvement and puts a lot of effort in it, but has issues in terms of confidence, tenacity and mental fortitude". Do you think it's a bit too much? Any recommendations/criticism in terms of style?

Comment: I must have been tired. Perseverance it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your "willpower" really does sound like the most literal definition of "mental endurance", but based on your sample, there are a few ways to go with this.

First is to focus not the abstract concept of mental strength over time, and instead on its results:

> ...but has issues in terms of confidence and **consistency**

or

> ...but has issues in terms of confidence and **self-discipline**

or just "discipline"... but this might have the connotation that the person as trouble with authority.

If you just mean the person's ability to doggedly stick to it:

> ...but has issues in terms of confidence and **tenacity**

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest either **determination** or **resolve** as suitable for your requirements.

> ...but has issues in terms of confidence and **determination**.

---

> . ..but has issues in terms of confidence and **resolve**.

I would say that both examples would seem like they require further elaboration in the next sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"...has a great desire for improvement and puts a lot of effort in it, but has issues in terms of confidence and ***commitment***"

Comment: What about "mettle"?

Answer (score 0):

How about **fortitude**?

Fortitude - Courage in pain or adversity. (OED)

‘she endured her illness with great fortitude’

Answer (score 0):

"Persistance" works because the context will determine whether mental or physical persistence is the relevant sense.