# Suitable word for a hardworking and resilient person

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, personality

I am writing a personal statement and my opening sentence is like this:

> I am _______. Being resilient in the face of hardships and difficulties, my friends and class fellows would call me so.

Now looking for a suitable word for this blank. Something which shows a hardworking and flexible personality. Kindly help.

Edit: looking for an easy and short word

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question, while it may be a duplicate, the duplicate question has been closed and as such new answers can not be submitted to that question. The other question was closed for lack of an example sentence (even though it has since been added). Since this question seems better, [the other question should be closed as duplicate of this one](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/is-it-appropriate-to-mark-an-earlier-poorer-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-later).

Comment: @JJJ my closure vote was for "too broad"  but I agree closing a new question with an older question that in turn is also closed is not the best practice, and seems counterproductive. Maybe this is worthy of a discussion on meta.

Comment: loosely related: 1. [Word for something that doesn't kill you but makes you stronger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245840/word-for-something-that-doesnt-kill-you-but-makes-you-stronger), 2. [Word to describe someone who rarely gets upset](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112242/word-to-describe-someone-who-rarely-gets-upset), 3. [Word that sounds like “metal” but means “grit”, “tenacity”, and “perseverance”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400751/word-that-sounds-like-metal-but-means-grit-tenacity-and-perseverance)

Comment: closely related: 1. [What do you call someone who is emotionally strong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315681/what-do-you-call-someone-who-is-emotionally-strong), 2. [Single word for “mental endurance”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150441/single-word-for-mental-endurance) 3. [An adjective to describe a person who has come back from failure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318417/an-adjective-to-describe-a-person-who-has-come-back-from-failure)

Comment: The following question alone attracted 32 answers: [What do you call a person who keeps on going despite setbacks? (in one word, a noun)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140158/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-keeps-on-going-despite-setbacks-in-one-word-a-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Stakhanovite](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stakhanovite) :***

> An exceptionally hard-working or zealous person.
>
> - as modifier *‘she was a Stakhanovite worker in the field of female suffering’*.

(ODO)

Comment: I usually downvote answers to duplicate questions, but this is an impressive new answer.

Answer (score 1):

- I am [industrious](https://www.etymonline.com/word/industrious).

From Etymonline:

> "characterized by energy, effort, and attention; marked by industry," from Middle French industrieux (c. 1500) and directly from Late Latin industriosus, from Latin industria "diligence, activity" (see industry). Of persons, "given to industry, working diligently," 1590s. It retains the etymological sense of the Latin word while industrial serves in the modern senses.

Answer (score 1):

**Stress-resistant** comes to mind, but it might come across as [overpraising](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overpraise) yourself (to take away that sentiment you might want to add concrete examples to illustrate why you believe you are stress-resistant).

According to [this publication in Stress](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3287388/) from a (neuro)biological point of view (emphasis is mine):

> "It is important to emphasize, therefore, that stress resistance does not imply the absence of the stress response. Instead, we suggest that high levels of stress resistance delays the “tipping point” from adaptive to maladaptive responses and increase the duration and/or intensity of stressor exposure needed to cross over. In other words, **individuals with high levels of stress resistance are able to endure a great deal of stress before experiencing negative effects.**"

Attribution: Fleshner, Monika, Steven F. Maier, David M. Lyons, and Murray A. Raskind. "The Neurobiology of the Stress-resistant Brain." Stress 14, no. 5 (2011): 498-502. Accessed May 13, 2018. doi:10.3109/10253890.2011.596865.

Answer (score 1):

You might do well with a noun alternative. How about **fortitude**?

From Dictionary.com

*:courage in pain or adversity.*

"she endured her illness with great fortitude"
synonyms:   courage, bravery, endurance, resilience, mettle, moral fiber, strength of mind, strength of character, strong-mindedness, backbone, spirit, grit, true grit, doughtiness, steadfastness; informalguts

Thus, your example becomes

*I have fortitude.*

Answer (score 1):

I would go for **Conscientious** if I were you.

Comment: Why? What does it mean? Why is it appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, I suggest this simpler word: **driven**, [according to Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/driven):

> (of a person) relentlessly compelled by the need to accomplish a goal; very hard-working and ambitious

In your sentence (I combined your two sentences into one):

> I am **driven:** resilient in the face of hardships and difficulties, my friends and class fellows would call me so.

Attribution: "Driven | Definition of Driven in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 13, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/driven.

Answer (score 1):

**dependable** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dependable)

> capable of being depended on; worthy of trust; reliable: a dependable
>   employee.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of to meaning "*resilient in the face of hardships and difficulties*" would be **unstoppable**. Other possiblities are **steadfast**, **resolute**, and **determined**, but for an opening sentence I like unstoppable best.

Of course, you may want to convey more than just resiliency, in which case another word might be more appropriate, but if that is the case you will have to elaborate on all that you are trying to convey.